# Consecutive numbers in lotto (again)

Tags: probability

There's already a similar question, but mine has a spin: in poker, why is drawing three of a kind on the deal less likely than two pair? Back to lotto: when the first number is drawn in lotto, the next number's relationship is a variable probability. It is not simply a matter of each draw has equal merit: it's the *relationship* that is the issue. For two consecutive numbers, once one number is drawn, the probability sum must now include the chances of a consecutive ball to the last one drawn, or to any other of the five drawn. For three in a row it gets even less likely. If that's not the case then poker is a scam and all the probabilities of drawing a royal flush compared to a dud hand are equal. If you believe that, then how about a nice friendly game? It's one dollar to ante up, but the dollar must have at least three consecutive numbers in its serial. :)

I must warn you that I just bought a twelve game ezipick that has two games with three consecutive numbers, so obviously my luck is running. Just don't know which way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand everything you're saying, but it seems to me you're looking at the question in a more complicated way than necessary. To get a rough sense of why three-of-a-kinds are less common than two pairs, consider how many three of a kinds there are. Independent of the suits involved, there are $\,13\,$ types, from three aces to three kings; now factoring in the suits, for each type of three-of-a-kind, there are $\,4\,$ possibilities: either no spade, or no heart, or no diamond, or no club. Thus there are a total of only $13 \times 4 = 52\,$ three-of-a-kinds.

Counting the number of two-pairs is a little more complicated. Again, we start independent of suits; it should be easy to see there is a much larger number of possibilities: aces & twos, aces & three, aces & fours, .... , aces & kings, twos & threes, twos & fours, twos & fives, .... , twos & kings, threes & fours, .... The actual number of possible two-pairs is $\,\binom{13}{2} = 78.\,$ If you're unfamiliar with binomial coefficients, there's another way to arrive at this number: there are twelve types involving aces , plus another eleven types involving twos, plus another ten types involving threes, etc. so the total number of types of two-pairs will be $\,12+11+10+...+1=78.\,$ Now factoring in the suits, there are $\,\binom{4}{2} = 6\,$ possibilities for each pair (here, if you're unfamiliar with the math, a quick count should suffice: spade & heart, spade & diamond, spade & club, heart & diamond, heart & club, diamond & club.) Thus we have a total of $\,78 \times 6 \times 6 = 2808\,$ two-pairs.

Of course, this isn't the complete story, as we still have to factor in the remaining cards in the hand, but if you're just looking for an intuitive explanation the above would be a good start.

For the complete calculation, we have to fill out the hands; there will of course be a higher number of ways of choosing the remaining two cards for the three-of-a-kind than there will be of choosing the one remaining card for the two-pairs (I'm assuming you're playing five-card) but the difference will not be enough to make up for the much larger number of two-pairs.

To choose the remaining two cards for the three-of-a-kind, we first have to choose their ranks; note that they have to have different ranks, otherwise our hand would be a full house. We can choose the two ranks in $\,\binom{12}{2} = 66\,$ ways. We can also arrive at this number by considering that there are 12 choices for the first rank (as the rank we've used for our three-of-a-kind is no longer available) and 11 choices for the second rank; however we have to divide by two as the order we choose the two ranks in is immaterial (e.g. choosing aces followed by sevens gives the same hand as choosing sevens followed by aces), so we have $\,\frac{12 \times 11}{2} = 66\,$ ways of choosing the ranks of the two cards. Then we have $\,4\,$ choices for the card from each rank; thus we have $\,66 \times 4 \times 4 = 1056\,$ ways of filling out the three-of-a-kind hand. Filling out the two-pairs hand is simpler; our two pairs eliminate two ranks from our choices, leaving us $\,44\,$ possibilities for the fifth card.

Thus the final count for the number of three-of-a-kinds is

$$13 \times 4 \times 1056 = 54912$$

while the number of two-pairs is

$$78 \times 6 \times 6 \times 44 = 123552$$

Using binomial coefficients, the counts would look like

$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{12}{2} \binom{4}{1} \binom{4}{1} = 54912 \quad {\small \text{and}} \quad \binom{13}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{44}{1} = 123552$$